# angularfire binding to primitive

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to bind to a primitive with angularfire. Here's how I"m doing it:

```
      $firebase(fb.child('counts/node')).$on('value', function (obj) {
        $scope.nodeCount = obj.snapshot.value
      })
```

Is this correct? This API seems very different from the rest of firebase. I expected to get an ss as callback and do `ss.val()` but that doesn't seem to be the case. Can someone confirm if this is how it's supposed to be or if I'm doing it wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, as outlined in the [getting started guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/) and [API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html), you should simply be accessing the data directly in the view:

```
// javascript
$scope.messages = $firebase(new Firebase(URL));

<!-- html -->
<li ng-repeat="message in messages">{{message}}</li>
```

If you want to iterate the data in a controller (bad) or service (better), you can read the keys in the order as the database by using $getIndex().

```
// javascript
var ref = $firebase(new Firebase(URL));
ref.$on('loaded', function() {
   angular.forEach(ref.$getIndex(), function(key) {
      console.log('the next message is', key, ref[key]);
   });
});
```

If you are, in fact, trying to synchronize a single primitive value, angularFire is hardly necessary:

```
$scope.primitive = null;
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
ref.on('value', function(snap) { $scope.primitive = snap.val(); });

$scope.saveValue = function(newValue) {
   ref.set(newValue);
};
```

But certainly possible:

```
// javascript
$scope.primitive = $firebase(new Firebase(URL));

<!-- html -->
<input ng-model="primitive.$value" />
```

All of this is covered in the above links, which should be treated as required reading before getting started with Angular + Firebase.

**changes in 0.8**

angularFire 0.8 will be out soon. It will change this structure a little bit, utilizing a $asArray(), $asObject(), and also providing a .then() method, so a bit more like this:

```
// javascript
var ref = $firebase(new Firebase(URL));
$scope.messages = ref.$asArray();

$scope.ref.then(function() {
   angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(message) {
      console.log('the next message is', message.$id);
   });
});

<!-- html -->
<li ng-repeat="message in messages">{{message}}</li>
```

Comment: `If you are, in fact, trying to synchronize a single primitive value, angularFire is hardly necessary:` Thanks for your help. I'm trying to stay with 1 api if that makes sense, just feels cleaner to me. I'm avoiding using the fb native apis. `$scope.primitive = $firebase(new Firebase(URL));` I'm probably misunderstanding but that doesn't work for me. That returns an object when I need the value inside.

Comment: I'm excited about it finally returning a promise and clarifying the type returned... Is it possible to try 0.8? Thanks.

Comment: The "but is certainly possible" section above shows how to use a primitive. $firebase is an API wrapper; it's always going to be an object, but you can access the primitive as shown.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, the formatting earlier confused me.

Comment: I guessed as much; surprising how a little spacing matters. :)

Comment: @Kato any idea on 0.8's release date?

Comment: @romanm I'm using the new $asArray from the array branch in git. It works okay for me.

Comment: I think using angularFire is preferable even for a single value - I think your raw Firebase example @Kato leaves a hanging `value` handler even after $destroy, for example.

Comment: AngularFire also leaves a hanging listener unless you use $bindTo() or manually call $destroy() when the scope is destroyed. However, since it's best to use services for these sorts of things, it's a judgment call (and completely proprietary) as to which ones need to be destroyed with $scope or kept around for re-use.